# Getting IMG tag by traversing through html elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the id value of the img tag using jquery? Once one of the divs with class containing polo.

this = line with **

```
<div style="width: 240px" class="outer">
   <img id="polo" class="apparelimage" src="images/Nike Polo - Navy.jpg" height="200px" width="200px" alt="" style="border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;">
   <br>
   <label style="font-size: small;"><b>COLORS</b></label>
   <div style="width: 280px; display: flex;">
      <div class="polo-black apparelimage" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
      <div class="polo-gray apparelimage" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: gray; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
      <div class="polo-lightblue apparelimage" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: lightblue; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
      <div class="polo-navy apparelimage" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: navy; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
      <div class="polo-white apparelimage" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: white; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Once one of the divs is clicked I want to traverse up through the elements and get the first elemwnt with and img tag. Then I want to alert the id of the img element.

```
$('.apparelimage').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;

        if (id == "") {
            id = alert($(this).closest('.outer').find("img").id);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `<img>` element is not a direct ancestor of the clicked `<div>` elements. But if you can add a class to the outermost div. you can then use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find it, and then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search back down.

```
<div class="apparelContainer" style="width: 240px">
   <img ...
```

Then you can use:

```
$('.apparelimage').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;

    if (id == "") {
        alert($(this).closest('.apparelContainer').find('img.apparelimage').html());
    }
});
```

---

NOTE: The OP has changed the code in the question to reflect what is shown above.

Regarding the second issue, you need to get the `id` property from the DOM element, but you have a jQuery object.

Use either:

```
$(this).closest('.outer').find("img").attr('id')
```

Or:

```
$(this).closest('.outer').find("img")[0].id
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs61eozt/)

Comment: I have to find the "img" because the id will not always be "#polo" because there are several other divs like this. Would i be able to do alert($(this).closest('.outerDiv').find("img").html());?

Comment: @user3788671 - That makes sense, Otherwise you would just use the `id` to find it. I have changed the code in my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am going up update my code. But it still is not coming back with anything

Comment: @user3788671 - You are trying t get the `id` property from a jQuery object. Use `.attr('id')` instead. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs61eozt/).

Answer (score 2):

try this .. this for divs id starts with polo

```
$('[class^="polo"]').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('id');
});
```

if you want id containing polo

```
$('[class*="polo"]').on('click',function(){.....});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vxnan9jr/)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `parent().find`, try `closest("img")` to traverse up.

Comment: The `<img/>` would have to be a direct ancestor in order for this to work (but images cannot have descendants).